# I've done bot typing in python, which works locally but not on the server. What's the problem?

Tags: wordpress, heroku, iframe, botframework, chatbot

I've done bot typing in python,

which works locally but not on the server.

What's the problem?

I write the Right Code,

And It works on Python Emulator.

But not on the server.

```
async def create_reply_activity_typing(request_activity: Activity, text: str, attachment: Attachment = None) -> Activity:
activity = Activity(
    type=ActivityTypes.typing,
    channel_id=request_activity.channel_id,
    conversation=request_activity.conversation,
    recipient=request_activity.from_property,
    from_property=request_activity.recipient,
    text=None,
    service_url=request_activity.service_url)
return activity
```

#### And below is the code that actually send the Activity.

```
async def request_handler(context: TurnContext) -> web.Response:
if context.activity.type == 'message':
  prompt_message = await create_reply_activity_typing(context.activity, None)
  time.sleep(5)
  await context.send_activity(prompt_message)
  return await handle_message(context)
```

Comment: It looks like you are creating your activity correctly. You actually only need to set the type. They adapter populates all the other values. Can you please add the code where you actually send the activities? Also, are you using BotChat or an iFrame?

Comment: Hi !   I'm using iframe. on wordpress. Also I'm using heroku Server. And I'm sorry for not paste screen shot.  please answer on my question pasted in here. https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-python/issues/147

Comment: @tdurnford  I just edit the question. And I have one more question , How to make the value appear directly on the user side when the user presses a button on the card?  The refer site is https://contososcubademo.azurewebsites.net/ . here.  User press the button on the card but it appears like user 'Type' the value. Please answer if you Know  the way.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I would have to see your code that creates the card to answer your follow up question. It looks like you've already asked a [question]() regarding this issue; however, it is currently On Hold. I would recommending adding your code snippets to the question before it gets shut down.

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of Web Chat you need to be aware of - Web Chat and Bot Chat. Note, Bot Chat is depreciated.

In regards to typing events, Bot Chat does not wait to display the next activity if it is showing a typing event. However, Web Chat does pause before rendering the next activity. Currently, the iFrame renders Bot Chat, and the Emulator uses Web Chat which is why your typing event works in the Emulator and not the iFrame. Even though the iFrame currently uses Bot Chat, in the next release, which should be in the next couple of days, the iFrame will be updated to render Web Chat.

You can either wait for the update or add a timeout to your code **after** you send the typing activity.

```py
prompt_message = await create_reply_activity_typing(context.activity, None)
await context.send_activity(prompt_message)

# Note the timeout needs to be after the activity is sent
time.sleep(5) 

return await handle_message(context)
```

Hope this helps!